# DirectML, Windows Insider Preview and DX SDK Debacle

Tags: windows, directx, direct3d, directx-12

So, I've got Windows  10.0.18358.1 installed, latest Visual Studio (17, not bothering with 19 as of yet), updated (Insider) Windows SDK which should include the DX12 SDK.

And, yet, I have no DXSDK_DIR environment variable set.

I can see all of the DX and D3D headers and libs in the windows kits folder, but their distribution doesn't really correspond to a typical include/bin/lib structure.

Suggestions on how to correct this? I'd settle for copy of anyone's `set` output 
that has this working.

(DirectML tag is because that is the feature that I require, and the source of all of this insanity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DXSDK_DIR` variable was only used by the legacy DirectX SDK and the 'beta DirectX 12 SDK' test vehicle, it's not used by the Windows 10 SDK as the standard `WindowsSDKDir` already includes the required headers & libraries.

If you are building with the Visual Studio build system, you don't have any special setup to use the DirectX 12 headers as they are all in the path already. Likely, your project is set to use the 10.0.17763 Windows 10 SDK by default, so to use the Windows 10 Insider SDK, you'll need to modify the project settings `<WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>` element to reference the newer 10.0.18xxx version.

If you are using some more manual build system, then you should use the include paths for the Windows 10 SDK side-by-side structure:

```
%WindowsSdkDir% is typically "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\"
%WindowsSDKVersion% is something like "10.0.17763.0\"
%arch% is "arm", "arm64", "x64", or "x86'

INCLUDE=%WindowsSdkDir%include\%WindowsSDKVersion%shared;
    %WindowsSdkDir%include\%WindowsSDKVersion%um; 
    %WindowsSdkDir%include\%WindowsSDKVersion%winrt; 
    %WindowsSdkDir%include\%WindowsSDKVersion%cppwinrt

LIB=%WindowsSdkDir%lib\%WindowsSDKVersion%um\%arch%
```

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directx-sdk--august-2009-) and [this blog post](https://aka.ms/dxsdk)

> The Windows 10 SDK does not include utilities which are instead shared source. For D3DX12, you can obtain the latest header from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Libraries/D3DX12)
>
> You may also want to look at [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started), [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex), and [DirectXMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh)
>
> For historic and usability reasons, DirectXMath *is* part of the Windows 10 SDK, but you can also get the latest version from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath). The recent Windows 10 SDKs also include the [HLSL compiler/D3DCompile API](https://aka.ms/Tuoxjd) including both the older `FXC.EXE` and the new [Shader Model 6](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler) `DXC.EXE`.
>
> You may also find the Visual Studio templates on [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) useful.

Comment: Thanks, Chuck. I'm working with a cmake project that needs these env vars set in order to function. Once THAT works, I'll have a .sln that I can use. I installed the 2010 SDK and that took care of the issue - entirely based on your suggestion. GDC will be happier.:) Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest reverting to the previous build and flagging the issue in the Feedback Hub. Also, if you haven't already, run chkdsk before and after install, just in case.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, and I will certainly do that. However, that does not help me solve my issue. If you have a technical suggestion or fix, please post it. (And, welcome to SO!)

Comment: Another note: there is no previous build to which I can revert. Chkdsk? Why? In this decade?